# Batch import NDVI files and create monthly average NDVI values

Tags: r, loops, raster, terra

I've downloaded just over 1000 NDVI MODIS files using the package Terra, which are from the years 2000-2022.

I've now mosaic'd the tiles together, so I have 502 mosaic .tif files with names such as:

```
mosaic_NDVI_2000_7_27.tif
```

I'd like to import them into R, and create 12 mean NDVI raster layers, one for each month.

I can't get around how to do that which is computationally efficient.

I'd appreciate your help with this!